# How to access view ID for service account that has already been granted permission in google analytics?

Tags: python, google-analytics, google-analytics-api, service-accounts

My task it to access data from a certain website using python, from google analytics.
I have created a service account.
My Higher up (who has given this task) has granted my service account read and analyze permission.
To extract the data, I need the view ID.
I thought we can access the view ID from here :
https://ga-dev-tools.web.app/account-explorer/

However the account explorer just keeps loading forever.
How else can I get the view ID and from where, for my service account which already has read and analyze permission?

Comment: Are you asking how to get the id programmatically? Else you can just look it up in the relevant view, it is the first line when you go to the analytics account in question and, in the admin section, open "view settings".

Comment: But about the analytics account, the website does not belong to me, I am just using a service account which has permissions. When I log into analytics.google.com, it asks me about my company or website, But its not mine.

Comment: With a service account, you cannot log interactively (via a browser) into GA.  But you can use the Management API in a script or programm to list all accounts, properties and views you have access to: https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/config/mgmt/v3/mgmtReference/management/accounts/list. Is that what you are looking for?

Comment: Yes, I was searching for this exactly for a long time :  to access views without creating acc on GA. Thank you.

Comment: I turned the comment into an answer, if it helped you you can "accept" it by clicking the green checkmark icon to the left of the answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With a service account, you cannot log interactively (via a browser) into GA.

But you can use the Management API in a script or program to list all accounts, properties and views you have access to, [as per the example given in the documemtation here](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/config/mgmt/v3/mgmtReference/management/profiles/list):

```
# Note: This code assumes you have an authorized Analytics service object.
# See the View (Profile) Developer Guide for details.

# Example #1:
# Requests a list of views (profiles) for the authorized user.
try:
  profiles = analytics.management().profiles().list(
      accountId='12345',
      webPropertyId='UA-12345-1').execute()

except TypeError, error:
  # Handle errors in constructing a query.
  print 'There was an error in constructing your query : %s' % error

except HttpError, error:
  # Handle API errors.
  print ('There was an API error : %s : %s' %
         (error.resp.status, error.resp.reason))

# Example #2:
# Retrieves views (profiles) for all properties of the user's account,
# using a wildcard '~all' as the webpropertyId.
profiles = analytics.management().profiles().list(accountId='12345',
                                                  webPropertyId='~all'
                                                 ).execute()

# Example #3:
# The results of the list method are stored in the profiles object.
# The following code shows how to iterate through them.
for profile in profiles.get('items', []):
  print 'Account ID                = %s' % profile.get('accountId')
  print 'Property ID           = %s' % profile.get('webPropertyId')
  print 'Internal Property ID  = %s' % profile.get('internalWebPropertyId')
  print 'View (Profile ID)         = %s' % profile.get('id')
  print 'View (Profile) Name       = %s' % profile.get('name')

  print 'Default Page = %s' %  profile.get('defaultPage')
  print 'Exclude Query Parameters        = %s' % profile.get(
      'excludeQueryParameters')
  print 'Site Search Category Parameters = %s' % profile.get(
      'siteSearchCategoryParameters')
  print 'Site Search Query Parameters    = %s' % profile.get(
      'siteSearchQueryParameters')

  print 'Currency = %s' % profile.get('currency')
  print 'Timezone = %s' % profile.get('timezone')
  print 'Created  = %s' % profile.get('created')
  print 'Updated  = %s' % profile.get('updated')
  print 'eCommerce Tracking = %s' % profile.get('eCommerceTracking')
  print 'Enhanced eCommerce Tracking = %s' % profile.get(
      'enhancedECommerceTracking')
```

The API still refers to "views" as profiles, that is a holdover from the transition to Universal Analytics years ago. Obviously this will not work for GA4, which no longer has views.